# scalar variable and simple delete statement

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have method DeleteAuthors which receives id of type integer. I want using dapper to delete all data from that table which BookId is equal to id received as parametar.

```
private void DeleteAuthors(int id)
{
    this.db.Query("DELETE FROM Author WHERE BookId = @id");
}
```

Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

So I've tried with this

```
private void DeleteAuthors(int id)
{
   this.db.Query("DELETE FROM Author WHERE BookId = @Id", new { Id = id});
}
```

and error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Dapper.dll
>
> Additional information: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you
>   set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id

id parametar variable is correctly populated with int value. I know this is simple but I'm struggle here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `db.Execute` instead of `db.Query` if you want to delete records:

```
int numDel = db.Execute("DELETE FROM Author WHERE BookId = @BookId;", new { BookId = Id }, null, null, null);
```

But you should use the `using` statement to ensure that the connection gets disposed/closed as soon as possible (even on error):

```
int numDel = 0;
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    db.Open();
    numDel = db.Execute("DELETE FROM Author WHERE BookId = @BookId;", new { BookId = Id }, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: @user2783193: from another question i've seen that you're using `FireBird` instead of sql-server as rdbms. I assume that it's also using a connection-pool by default, so the `using` recommendation is still true. But you should of course use `... new FbConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about replacing @ in query

but following will also work:

```
private void DeleteAuthors(int id)
{
    this.db.Query(string.Format("DELETE FROM Author WHERE BookId = {0}",id));
}
```